# Postgres triggers that notify and then listen for a response on a channel?

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, procedures

I'm looking for a way to do a request response pattern inside a trigger. This would be used to perform additional (more complex) data validation.

More concretely, something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER create_user
BEFORE INSERT
   ON users
   FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  --- trigger 3rd party validation code
  NOTIFY creating new.user

  --- listen for 3rd party code to notify with the result
  return LISTEN created

END;
```

Would this be possible to do in postgres? Thanks!

Comment: You need to provide specific information about what you are trying to do.  What's a "request response pattern" in this context?  What /exactly/ do you want the trigger to do?

Comment: i want it to trigger more complex validation in another language (like Golang, PHP, Node.js) and then respond with true or false, then have the trigger reject or resolve.

Comment: At 6,000+ rep you should know better than to ask a question in this way. An answer to your question would be as simple as "Yes", but I guess you are looking for something more specific. If so, make your question more specific.

Comment: I find being concise tends to work better on Stack Overflow. The heading says it all – even a "yes" would be helpful to me actually, then I know to dig further, but I haven't seen any way to LISTEN and NOTIFY inside a Postgres trigger. I've updated the title to hopefully clarify it some more.

Comment: A trigger can absolutely `notify` other listeners. However a trigger that listens, doesn't really make sense because it could only process messages when it was fired, which kind of defeats the purpose of the listening in my eyes.